# WPF Dependency Property And InotifyChanged Property

Tags: wpf

What is the real use of use/create Dependency property during real scenario?

If we are using notification purpose then i will choose InotifyChanged Property.

I have never seen/used real use of Dependency Property in real time projects?

Can somebody tell me where DP is required in Realtime Scenrios?

Comment: What is the real use of DP in WPF,if InotifyCHanged is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created a custom control with properties that you want to be **bindable** (e.g. following code), you cannot use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you must use a `DependencyProperty`.

Assume you have a `UserControl` like this:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public List<ItemViewModel> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (List<ItemViewModel>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(List<ItemViewModel>), typeof(MyUserControl ), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Then you can set a binding to `ItemsSource` (which is a **DependencyProperty**) in your main window this way:

```
<uc:MyUserControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"  />
```

**As Summary:**

In general, a binding looks like this: `T = "{Binding S}"`

- `T` is the **Target** of the binding.
- `S` is the **Source** of the binding.
- `T` is only allowed to be a **DependencyProperty**. e.g:

  MyDependencyProperty="{Binding something}"
- `S` is often an **INPC-Property**. e.g:

  something="{Binding MyINPCProperty}"

Comment: If i will also implement InotifyCHanges property  on custom user control ,Can i also bind it ? right ? if you have created ItemViewModel then why you are creating DP?

Comment: My basic question why you have created ITEMSOURCE as a DP ? I want to Understand Real use of DP at Implemenatation Level?

Comment: When you create a `UserControl` (e.g. a custom `ListBox`) you expect it to to be used several times and each time you should be able to set different `ItemsSource` right? in one instance  `ItemsSource = "{binding a}"` in another instance  `ItemsSource = "{binding b}"`.

Comment: Now `a` and `b` can be INPC properties (because they are source of a binding) but `ItemsSource` has to be DP  (because it's the target of a binding). If you define a normal or INPC property as the target of binding, you will get a Runtime error.

Comment: But i can bind it ItemsSource  through all different times with Inotifychanged also correct?

Comment: Why we do need here DP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84920/discussion-between-bahman-aries-and-sudhir-net).

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx):

> The purpose of dependency properties is to provide a way to compute
>   the value of a property based on the value of other inputs. These
>   other inputs might include system properties such as themes and user
>   preference, just-in-time property determination mechanisms such as
>   data binding and animations/storyboards, multiple-use templates such
>   as resources and styles, or values known through parent-child
>   relationships with other elements in the element tree. In addition, a
>   dependency property can be implemented to provide self-contained
>   validation, default values, callbacks that monitor changes to other
>   properties, and a system that can coerce property values based on
>   potentially runtime information. Derived classes can also change some
>   specific characteristics of an existing property by overriding
>   dependency property metadata, rather than overriding the actual
>   implementation of existing properties or creating new properties.